# R Tensorflow error message: Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to follow the tensorflow example in R at

https://rpubs.com/fhernanb/TF_simple_linear_reg

however I get the following error

```
> beta1 <- tf$Variable(tf$random_uniform(shape(1L), -10, 10), name="b1")

Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
  AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'random_uniform'
```

When I run a configuration diagnostic, I get the following (username changed for privacy reasons)

```
> py_discover_config("tensorflow")
python:         /Users/MyUsername/tensorflow/bin/python
libpython:      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-darwin/libpython3.7.dylib
pythonhome:     /Users/MyUsername/tensorflow/bin/..:/Users/MyUsername/tensorflow/bin/..
virtualenv:     /Users/MyUsername/tensorflow/bin/activate_this.py
version:        3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 26 2018, 23:26:24)  [Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
numpy:          /Users/MyUsername/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.19.4
tensorflow:     /Users/MyUsername/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow

python versions found: 
 /Users/MyUsername/tensorflow/bin/python
 /Users/MyUsername/tensorflow/bin/python3
 /usr/bin/python3
 /usr/local/bin/python3
 /usr/bin/python
 /Users/MyUsername/afdko_env/bin/python
 /Users/MyUsername/venv/bin/python
>
```

Can someone please inform me on how I can fix this issue please?

Comment: Can you try with `random.uniform` instead of `random_uniform` ?

Comment: @TFer2 unfortunately I get a similar error message: `Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
  AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'random.uniform' `

Comment: Does [this](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/reference/keras/initializer_random_uniform/) help you ?

Comment: @TFer2 thank you; this function it's a part of the `keras` library. when I type it in I get `<tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops_v2.RandomUniform>` as the output.

Comment: I'm also ok with finding any other example for using tensorFlow in R that works

Comment: Did you tried this `tf$random$uniform(shape(1L), -10, 10)`?

Comment: @TFer2 Thank you! This helped a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have received this `AttributeError` because there is no attribute by the name `random_uniform` in the current Tensorflow for R support.

Please replace `random_uniform` with `tf$random$uniform`, your issue will be resolved.

Complete working code as shown below

```
beta1 <- tf$Variable(tf$random$uniform(shape(1L), -10, 10), name="b1")
```